# SQL Server - Update columns in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to triggers and am trying to get to grips with them. I have a database for a sport booking company which includes the tables events, events / bookings and bookings (which contains details of the people who book events).

I want to create a trigger so that when a new event is added to the event table the person in the booking table with the least bookings will add one to their `amount_of_bookings` column however I'm unsure how to use triggers that change data in a table based on changes made to another table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

So far I have the following which I am working on:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Test] 
ON  [dbo].[Event]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Booking_Coordinators
    SET amount_of_bookings = amount_of_bookings + 1;
END
GO
```

Update: I have created a trigger which will add 1 to the amount of bookings column but it does this for every user in the bookings table. I need to change the query so it does it for the user with the least bookings.

Comment: It is really simple. In trigger any valid SQL commands will work. The only thing that differs is that you can access special rows/tables that are being inserted, updated, deleted. Try something and then post a more specific question.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run above trigger? What issues do you see with your code

Comment: @rs I dont get any errors but it adds 1 to all of the 'event bookers' in the booking table I need to alter the code so it only adds 1 to the user with the least bookings

Comment: can you post table structure or Id from `Booking_Coordinators` table

Comment: @rs the table is made up of 4 columns: booking_coordinatorID (PK) (int), booking_coordinator_forename (varchar), booking_coordinator_surename (varchar), ammount_of_bookings (numeric). Thanks for your help

Comment: if there are multiple persons with least booking value, do you want to update value for all of them?

Comment: @rs yes please, I've set the data at the moment so there is only one user who has 0 bookings so they should be the person updated but the final trigger will hopefully update them both if they both have the least number of bookings. Thank you

Comment: Do you always want to update only one row or all rows with the minimum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can change your update statement in trigger to

```
UPDATE Booking_Coordinators A
SET A.amount_of_bookings = A.amount_of_bookings + 1
WHERE A.amount_of_bookings = (SELECT MIN(X.amount_of_bookings)
                               FROM Booking_Coordinators X);
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help